# How to make jQuery automatically retry a load() if it fails?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing some content replacement via jquery load() on a number of places on page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#row').load('/getStudentDetails',{studentId:3});
  });
</script>
```

On my dev server things work perfectly. On my live server sometimes it gives me a "request is invalid" error which I can see in firebug. I think the server is getting overwhelmed, or perhaps some caching module is getting confused with several requests. I'll try to figure out that issue separately, but also simply want it to retry the same request (once) if it fails. Is there a slick jQuery way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it slick, but you could use the callback function of `$.load`.  If the status is `error`, you can redo the load.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#row').load('/getStudentDetails',{studentId:3}, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if(status == 'error') {
      $('#row').load('/getStudentDetails',{studentId:3});
    }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work for you.

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {studentId : 3},
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            setTimeout('doAjax()', 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

If your server is getting swamped I would recommend the delay with setTimeout to wait a little bit before trying again, otherwise it will hammer your server even harder.

Edit: I didn't notice you said only once. You can wrap the setTimeout in a counter, so the recursion does not just repeat. Or if you decide you want it to keep trying, this is a good way for it to work until you get a response.