# jquery .load() function with retry functionality

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a jquery plugin that attempts to load a url multiple times until success is reached?

I did read: [How to make jQuery automatically retry a load() if it fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298854/how-to-make-jquery-automatically-retry-a-load-if-it-fails)

But I am sure there has to be something more elegant, perhaps a plugin that displays a DIV when a retry is being attempted, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeRequest() {    
    $('#container_id').load(url, "", callbackFunction(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest));    
}

function callbackFunction (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if(textStatus == 'error') {
        // Yes, it failed
        $('#container_id').html('<p>Retrying...</p>');
        sleep(200);
        makeRequest();
    }
}
```